# What is the use of manifest list in context of docker containers?

Tags: docker, containers, windows-server-2016

I am trying to pull a image from docker hub using a command on windows server 2016

```
docker pull alpine
```

The command returns an error as follows
**no supported platform found in manifest list**

I am not sure what is manifest list and how is this related? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be due to OS compatibility as specified [here](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1100)

To resolve this try to *Right click* on Docker and *select* **Switch to Windows containers** or try adding the ***--experimental*** flag to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was pulling OpenJDK:8 using windows cmd. The container was Windows. I change the container to Linux container and the problem solved.